# Python regular expression: remove non-ASCII characters and words ending in number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to substitute with " " from a string all non-ASCII characters (accents, symbols), then substitute all words ending with numbers.

I thought r'\W|\b[^a-z]*[^a-z]\b'  would do it because I think it says "remove non-ASCII characters, or remove whole words starting with 0 or more non-letters and ending with non-letters". By non-letters I mean everythign that is not matched by [a-z]. However, "hey2","a2","1a3" are still there

```
#remove all these words:
re.sub(r'\W|\b[^a-z]*[^a-z]\b',' ', "1 123 - hey2 a2 1a3 ".lower()) 
>>>' hey2 a2 1a3 '
#keep all these words:
re.sub(r'\W|\b[^a-z]*[^a-z]\b',' ', "1st first a2a 2bb esta' ".lower()) 
>>>'1st first a2a 2bb esta  '          #This works
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you mean "non-ASCII" when saying non-Unicode. What is the expected result? Try `re.sub(r'\W|\b\w*[\d_]\b', ' ', s)`

Comment: You need to  clarify what you mean by non-letters, too. Right now, it is not quite clear.

Comment: non-Unicode: I found this in the python documentation for the re package. I'm ok with non-ASCII.
I clarify non-letters but I mean everything that is not a letter of the alphabet like (letter like s é z are ok, numbers, symbols, accents like * 4 ' are not).

Comment: Ok, so does `re.sub(r'\W|\b\w*\d\b', ' ', s)` work for you? If it is Python 2.x, `re.sub(r'\W|\b\w*\d\b', ' ', s, flags=re.U)`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : that seems to work! If you write an answer I will accept it. If you don't mind, what is the [\d_] part? Why is "\d_" (all decimals and underscore) inside the square brackets? Thank you

Comment: If you do not want to match words  ending with `_`, just replace `[\d_]` with `\d` as I suggested above. I think I was a bit inattentive when reading the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove non-unicode characters and words ending in number

It seems you want to remove any non-word char (matched with `\W` pattern) and any "word" (a sequence of letters/digit/`_`, `\w` pattern) ending with a digit.

So, you may use

```
re.sub(r'\W|\b\w*\d\b', ' ', s)
```

Note that in case you are dealing with Unicode strings in Python 2.x, you need to pass the `re.UNICODE` flag to make `\W` and `\w` Unicode aware.

**Pattern details**

- `\W` - a non-word char (any char that is not a letter, digit or `_`)
- `|` - or
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\w*` - zero or more (`*`) word chars
- `\d` - a digit
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Note that if you want to treat a `_` char as a non-word char, replace `\W` with `[\W_]` and `\w` with `[^\W_]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a (dot). before the "*".

".*" means 0 or more number of any character(s).

```
  re.sub(r'\W|\b[^a-z]*[^a-z]\b',' ', "1 123 - hey2 a2 1a3 ".lower()) 

In [6]: re.sub(r'\W|\b[^a-z].*[^a-z]\b',' ', "1 123 - hey2 a2 1a3 asdasd".lower())
Out[6]: ' asdasd'
```

Comment: No, that removes almost everything in the second expression. In particular I want to keep words like "1st". That is why I put * after [^a-z].